# How 'aaa'['toUpperCase'].apply('abc') works?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner of JavaScript.

I am really curious about how the code works..!!

Does anyone could explain how the code down below works, please?

It seems different from just `'abc'.toUpperCase();`

```
'aaa'['toUpperCase'].apply('abc');  // ABC
```

Comment: How do you think it is different?

Comment: Upvoted. This is actually an interesting question I would like to see answered too.

Comment: This is just a few pieces of standard JavaScript syntax, which part specifically isn't clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's equivalent to `'aaa'.toUpperCase.apply('abc')`, if that helps.

In JavaScript, objects are really just associative arrays. The dot notation `foo.bar` is just a convenience shorthand for `foo['bar']` that works when the array key string (`bar` in this case) has the form of an identifier - all letters plus maybe some underscores, and digits as long as it doesn't start with one.

So when you call a method on an object, you're really just looking up the value stored in the array slot whose key is the method name. For methods, that value is a function, or "closure", which you can then call using the `()` syntax.

But for method names, the slot on the object itself is usually actually empty! That causes Javascript to look it up on the *prototype* object shared by all objects of the same type; this is how JavaScript's prototype-based inheritance works. In your case, the string `'aaa'` doesn't actually have anything stored under the key `toUpperCase`, so JS looks at the String prototype to find it. That way all Strings have a common set of methods you can call on them – without having to store copies of those methods inside every string in your program.

By itself, `'aaa'.toUpperCase` is just another inert value. It happens to represent a function (or closure), but until you do something to cause it to run, it's no more active than a number or string. You can pass it around to other method calls, store it in other variables or properties, do whatever you want with it.

Once you do call it, it will get an invocant – the value of `this` inside the method call – that depends on where the call is in relation to the property lookup. Usually you just call a method immediately in the same expression where you retrieve it from an object, in which case the invocant is that same object. This behavior is more JavaScript syntax magic at work; `foo.bar()` is effectively a shortcut for `foo.bar.apply(foo)` that keeps you from having to repeat the object expression `foo`.

If you make a copy of the method and call it without an explicit object reference, it will inherit the value of `this` from the calling context. And likely complain that the referenced object is not the expected type.

But methods themselves are also objects, and they have their own methods that you can call on them, including one called `apply` that lets you call a method with a passed-in object as invocant. That's what your code does - looking up the method via `'aaa'` but then actually calling it on `'abc'` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know the method also can be notated with brackets! Also, your answer helped me to build up new concepts of objects and how this method actually works in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's actually just equivalent to `''.toUpperCase.apply('abc')`. The content of the string on the left of `toUpperCase` doesn't make a difference. What does this mean? `toUpperCase` is a function available on every string in JavaScript. And `apply` is a function available on every function in JavaScript. It can be used to change the value of `this` inside a function.

So, if you split your code this way, you understand what's happening:

```
const upperCase = ''.toUpperCase;
upperCase.apply('abc'); // ABC
```

It so happens that String#toUpperCase uses the value of `this` inside it to convert to an uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> All String instances inherit from String.prototype. Changes to the
>   String prototype object are propagated to all String instances.

So all strings inherits a series of [methods and properties](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods), and since you can access properties with `dot` or square `notation`.

Therefore this code:

```
'aaa'['toUpperCase'].apply('abc');  // ABC
```

Equivalent to this:

`'aaa'.toUpperCase.apply('abc');  // ABC`

and also equivalent to:

```
String.prototype['toUpperCase'].call('Hello')

// or 

String.prototype.toUpperCase.call('Hello')
```

`apply` and also `call` are functions inherited from `Function.prototype` and allow to execute functions in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `'aaa'` is a string, so you can apply any methods for string. 
`'aaa'['toUpperCase']` will return a function call toUpperCase. You can use any other method for string like `charAt` or even attribute like `length`. Thus 'aaa'['toUpperCase'].apply('abc'); will return 'ABC' as a final result

Answer (score 0):

First, `'aaa'['toUpperCase']` is equvelent to `'aaa'.toUpperCase`, basically, `'aaa'` is a string literal, every string has a [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) property which is a function.

Then, [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it's a method available for all functions. It has the following signature `yourFunction.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])` which calls a function with a given **this** value, and arguments provided as an array. Basically, you can think it as `thisArg.yourFunction(argsArray)`

So, when you call `'aaa'.toUpperCase()`, **this** is `'aaa'`. But when you call `'aaa'.toUpperCase.apply('abc')`, **this** now is `'abc'`, so you can think it as `'abc'.toUpperCase()`, so the result is `'ABC'`

Based on the above analysis，`'aaa'['toUpperCase'].apply('abc');` returns `'ABC'`.